# jquery - chaning the background-color based on clientWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I am trying to get my page to change it's background-color with jQuery.The problem is that the color only changes when i refresh the page  and will not change when being zoomed in and zoomed out.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
if(ww < 769){

 $("body").css("background-color","yellow");

}else{
$("body").css("background-color","green");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  hgfhfhg
</body>
```

Comment: `$(window).on('load resize', handler);` or use CSS media queries. And to check for viewport width in javascript, use [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)  ([polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/))

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS media query for this:

```
body{
    background-color: yellow;
}

@media (min-width: 769px){
    /* Styles here are only applied when the width
       of the window is more or equal to 769px */

    body{
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w3vceb50/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is only checking on pageload for window size.  It does not continuously check.  If you wanted something to fire on resize, then you'd use this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

It's worth mentioning that the resize event (as well as the scroll event) fire many times as this occurs and best practice is to put something called a [debouncer](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) on it.  However, if you do this with CSS media queries, everything becomes much simpler.  In your CSS, you'll need the following:

```
body{
      background-color:yellow;
}

@media screen and (max-width:769px){
   body{
      background-color:green;
   }
}
```

And in the head of your HTML add the following tag:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'/>
```

Now on resize, the background should change.

Answer (score 0):

Use "resize" method for that. The "ready" method will get called once the DOM is ready.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
if(ww < 769){

    $("body").css("background-color","orange");

}else{
$("body").css("background-color","green");
}
});
```